# How to boolean with non manifold geometry?

Tags: modifiers

(note : my understanding of manifold is that the object is solid, closed. Tell me if I'm wrong)

I'm working in an industry. I use Blender to adapt ingeniery/simplify CAD 3D models of a power plant for making virtual tour. Part of this work is about making a cut in the plant (like a cake you cut a part to see the inside).

The 3D models are very complex and requires a lot of work to be manifold (because the CAD software we use makes ugly 3D, with disconected faces and the vertices rarely are where they should be). I don't have the time to make all of them manifold (a power plant is a lot of machines...).

If no error of me, Blender Boolean requires Manifold geometry, and I can't always have it. So to boolean-cut I'm stuck in using 3DSmax where there is the « Boolean » tool, which accept non-manifold geometry (edit: but just cut, it doesn't create new faces).

It's a pain to switch between 2 3D softwares, and I would like to continue using Blender. Is there a way in blender to cut non-manifold geometry?

Comment: How about the knife project tool?

Comment: I have looked at the knife tool. I understand that it can add new edges. How could I use it to cut all the items in the same way? Like in this image (knowing in my case it's an angle cut, not a flat cut)? http://www.ikonet.com/fr/ledictionnairevisuel/images/qc/coupe-une-centrale-hydroelectrique-68230.jpg

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will demonstrate my approach on Suzanne so that it is a bit more complex than say, a cube.

1. Setup the "knife cutter". For this I use a simple mesh with 3 vertices. Notice that the cursor is set to the pivot point for easy rotation control.

[image]

2. Perform the knife project.

[image]

3. Clean up the cut out vertices. Notes: use wireframe mode so the selection goes "through" the mesh, don't select the verts along the cut line...just the ones inside.

[image]

Comment: I'm happy with, thanks :) Here a variation of your 3rd step; after cut you can select the vertices of the cut and then Ctrl+E (Edge Split) to divide in two parts (most of the time it work)

Comment: Correction of what I said : your 3rd step works better than using edge split